# How to iterate through elements of CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

**Brief description:**
I got an instance of `CTreectrl` class where objects are stored, when an object is selected corresponding list report for that object is displayed.
I need to **adjust width of columns** of an instance of the class MyListCtrl which derives from `CListCtrl` so that data in that columns can be seen by user without resizing of columns.

**How I approach my task:**
I implement method InitColumnWidth  which is called when object is selected from the tree

```
    void COwnListCtrl::InitColumnWidth ( unsigned const * defwidth, BOOL chars )
        {
            /* find the largest string in each column and set column width accordingly
            so that user no longer need to manually adjust columns width */

            RECT r;
            GetClientRect ( & r );
            int* arrOfMaxColumnWidth = new int[NumCol]; // array where max length for columns will be stored
            for (int i = 0; i < NumCol; ++i)
                arrOfMaxColumnWidth[i] = 0; // initialize
            tstring dataInColumn;
            double Scale = ( defwidth && chars ) ? GetCharAveWidth ( * GetFont () ) : ( r.right * 0.01 );
            int numberOfVisitedItems = 0;
            do
            {
                dataInColumn = _T(""); // initialize
                for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col)
                {
                    //DWORD const itemData = this->GetItemData(numberOfVisitedItems);

                    dataInColumn = this->GetSubItemString(this->GetItemData(numberOfVisitedItems), col); 
                /* 1-st varaint returns only first row of the list 
           because GetItemData always returns zero, but I need to visit all rows */
                    dataInColumn = this->GetSubItemString(numberOfVisitedItems, col); 
   /* 2-nd variant, works for most objects from CTreeCtrl, but for a few of them assertion is raised, system reports on the corrupted heap and application terminates*/
                    if (dataInColumn.length() > arrOfMaxColumnWidth[col])
                        arrOfMaxColumnWidth[col] = dataInColumn.length();
                }
                ++numberOfVisitedItems;
            }
            while(dataInColumn.length() != 0); /* do{} while loop is used to get number of rows in the table
                                       as long as an empty string is read, which means that all rows were read*/
            for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col)
                int tmp = ColWidth[col] = arrOfMaxColumnWidth[col] * Scale;
            ColWidth[0] = 100;
```

Need help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this (replace your `for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col)` with the code below):

```
for (int col = 0; col < NumCol; ++col)
{
    int len = 0;
    for(int row = 0; this->GetItemCount(); ++row)
    {
        CString item = this->GetItemText(row, col);
        if(item.GetLength() > len) len = item.GetLength();
    }
    if (len > arrOfMaxColumnWidth[col])
        arrOfMaxColumnWidth[col] = len; // should you multiple it to Scale?
}
```

Comment: this isn`t working because this->GetItemCount() returns 0, that can be the case of that???

Comment: If you have a virtual list, you need to call SetItemCount() method.

Comment: so I need to find the code snippet where items are added to the my List and invoke there SetItemCount() with argument == number of items I am going to add???

Comment: Not really. You just need to find this code and check what global variable is used as a number of rows. I bet it will be `NumRow`

Comment: no there is no NumRow or any variables with even closer resemblance, instead I found the code snippet where items are inserted and modified it that each time item is inserted item count is updated but this takes no effect int COwnListCtrl::Insert(DWORD itemData, int pos)
{
 
  int newItemCount = this->GetItemCount() + 1;
    this->SetItemCount(newItemCount); 
    /* OK 24.04.2013, initially wasn`t implemented, 
    that resulted in lots of errors when operating with COwnListCtrl(ex. width adjucement)*/ 
  return InsertItem ( LVIF_PARAM, pos, _T ( "" ), 0, 0, 0, itemData );
}

Comment: It definitely looks like a virtual list. Please google it, if you do not what it is. In short, the actual data is not stored in the list, it is in an container of some sort, that holds the data. What you really need to do is search for `OnGetDispInfo` method that I bet will contain a big `switch` statement where it will grab some data from an CArray (or something) and display it on the screen. You need to use the same logic to calculate the length of your text. So, instead of `this->GetItemText(row, col)` in the code above you would get the text from this container

Comment: thank you for you time and effort in trying to solve my task. I add +1 to your unswer, I shall get aquiantied with info you advised me in case if it helps to sort out my problem - I shall accept your answer. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel. If you just want to resize the columns to fit the text try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumCol; ++i)
    ListView_SetColumnWidth( m_hWnd, i, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE );
```

Comment: You should probably set `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER` for the last column, to have it use the remaining space.

Comment: A matter of personal taste I guess but I'd only do that for a fixed width list control, like in a dialog, and not for a list view contained in a resizing frame.

Comment: True. Reading my comment again, that's not what I had wanted to say. More like: You might want to consider mentioning `LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER` in your answer.